# Avoid two request at same time in firestore

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I created a function to communicate with the firestore database. 
First, check if there is something in the relation. If not then add something. 
If something already exists then use the data and then delete the entry in the queried relation. But you have to add that in the function(else section). And now the question arises what happens when two users simultaneously perform the function. 
Is there a way to put the second user in a queue while the first user is done with the request?

```
let ref = db.collection('relation1').doc('test').collection('user');
      var checkForAdd = ref.get().then(snapshot => {
        if(snapshot.size < 1){
            db.collection('relation1').doc('test').collection('user').add({
                user: 'Test',
                createdAt: Date.now()
            }).catch(err =>{
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
```

Comment: That's exactly what [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cloud Firestore supports atomic operations for reading and writing data. In a set of atomic operations, either all of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

```
// Create a reference to the user doc you want to create if it doesn't exist.
const userCollectionRef = db.collection('relation1').doc('test').collection('user');
const userDocRef = userCollectionRef.doc('documentID');

return db.runTransaction(transaction => {
    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction.get(userDocRef).then(userDoc => {
        if (userDoc.exists) {
            // If something already exists then use the data and
            // then delete the entry in the queried relation.
        } else {
            transaction.update(userDocRef, {
                user: 'Test',
                createdAt: Date.now()
            });
        }
    });
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
}).catch(error => {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But can you tell me why userDoc.exists is always false even if something is inside?

Comment: I left the doc empty, because I want to prefer an autoid in that case(doc())

Comment: An auto ID itself is supposed to be unique, so the doc should never exist

Comment: Is there a possibility to check if the whole collection is empty or not? Maybe with the check of the size or something?

Comment: Explain the context of what you're doing a bit more, have you hardcoded the child paths into your `userCollectionRef` or are there any dynamic values? The 'user' collection, how many documents do you expect to have in there at a time?